# Angular returns result of OPTIONS and not the method called

Tags: angular, api, cors

I have some Angular 4 application given and expect a strange bug.
There is a service, myService. It has a request method which is used in other parts of the application.

(Partial view)

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { SweetAlertService } from 'ng2-sweetalert2';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Toast, ToastsManager } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';

@Injectable()
export class myService {

    constructor(
        @Inject(SweetAlertService) swal: SweetAlertService,
        private http: Http,
        public toaster: ToastsManager
    ) {
        this._swal = swal;
    }

    public absTop(el) {
        return el.offsetParent ? el.offsetTop + this.absTop(el.offsetParent) : el.offsetTop;
    }

    public post(path: string, requestData?: any, settings?: any) {
        !settings && (settings = {});
        settings.method = 'post';
        return this.request.call(this, path, requestData, settings);
    }

    public get(path: string, requestData?: any, settings?: any) {
        !settings && (settings = {});
        settings.method = 'get';
        return this.request.call(this, path, requestData, settings);
    }

    public request(path: string, requestData?: any, settings?: any): Observable<Response> {
        settings = settings || {};
        var supErr = settings.suppressError;

        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers })

        let prefix: string = window['requestUrlPrefix'] || '';

        if (!window['countLoadings']) {
            window['countLoadings'] = 1;
        } else {
            ++window['countLoadings'];
        }

        if (document.body.className.indexOf("load-mask") < 0) {
            document.body.className += " load-mask";
        }

        var toid = setTimeout(function() {
            if (window['countLoadings'] > 0) {
                if (document.body.className.indexOf("load-spinner") < 0) {
                    document.body.className += " load-spinner";
                }
            }
        }, 400);

        let method = settings && settings.method ? settings.method : 'post';
        let obs = this.http[method](prefix + path, JSON.stringify(requestData), options).share();

        if (settings.timeout) {
            obs = obs.timeout(settings.timeout);
        }

        let onErr = (err) => {
            let resp = '';

            let status = err.status ? err.status : err.name;

            if (supErr === true || supErr == status || (Object.prototype.toString.call(supErr) === '[object Array]' && supErr.indexOf(status) >= 0)) {
                // supress the error message
            } else {
                this.swal({
                    text: 'The is an error!<br>' + resp,
                    type: 'error'
                });
            }
            fin();
        };

        let fin = () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (--window['countLoadings'] === 0) {
                    document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(/\bload-mask\b/, '').replace(/\bload-spinner\b/, '');
                    clearTimeout(toid);
                }
            }, 1);
        };

        obs.subscribe(
            fin,
            onErr
        );

        return obs;
    }
```

The backend part is absolutely correct. All required headers are returned. CORS is always set to the origin (in dev-mode), so there aren't any problems.

The problem part is here:

```
...cut...
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
    public settings: SettingsService,
    public myService: myService,
...cut...
        myService.post('/someEndpoint', null, {
            timeout: 10000,
            suppressError: [412, 403]
        }).subscribe((ret) => {

            console.log(ret);
...cut...
```

`console.log(ret)` always shows the result (body) of the preflight request done by the browser. If I disable CORS (f.e. in Safari) it works without any issues as the right data is returned. But with enabled CORS (as it is in prod) the wrong data is available in the subscribe section.

Additional info (example):

- the app is available under `app.somedomain.com`
- the api is available under `api.somedomain.com`

What is the problem here? (I have no idea about Angular :D)

**UPDATE**

I tried simply adding a method to make an api call. It looks this like:

```
public test(): Observable<Response> {

        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers })

        return this.http
            .post('http://api.somedomain.com/someEndpoint', '{}' ,options)
            .map(response => {
                console.log(response)
                return response
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And I still get the response from the OPTION call of the browser...

I call the method in some component this way:

```
this.test = this.myService.test();
```

Comment: what is jfs? an isntance of myService taht wraps the http service? it looks like you're calling request directly, which should never be done because you're not setting a method

Comment: sorry, updated the code. How should it be called?

Comment: didn't you write this service? you need to call the proper http request type for what you're trying to do, eg get, put, post, delete... request should really be a private method only used internally by the service

Comment: it's not my code but I have to fix it... As I can see, post is called as default method type (`this.http[method]`). Even changing to `post` in AppComponent has no change

Comment: it's not being done correctly, this whole thing is an absolute mess. Not sure where you got it, but my advice is to toss it out and never use code from whoever gave you this again

Comment: I didn't write the code. But thank you, maybe I try to rewrite it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer seems to be very simple...

`options.withCredentials = true` was missing... (in requests)